# How to extract date in different language from single text file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, logic, nsdate

I have a text file which contains block of information distinguishable by "Added on". Each body of meaningful strings are separated by `########` (later I persist them to disk using Core Data).

I am saving them to a temporary NSArray of NSString File as follows:

```
NSURL *url = [self urlOfResource:@"List" withExrension:@"txt"];

NSError *error = error;
NSString *originalContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
if (error) NSLog(@"ERROR READING CONTENT OF FILE: %@", error);

// separeting string and saving it to NSArray
NSArray *seperateStringBody = [originalContent componentsSeparatedByString:@"########"];
```

Now using for loop, I am separating relevant content on the basis of Added date(which belongs to every discrete body of text in same text file)

```
    for(NSString *body in seperateStringBody){
    //I am showing only relevant code here
    NSRange range = [removedNewLine rangeOfString:@"Added on "];
    NSUInteger startRange = range.location+range.length;
    NSString *dateString = [removedNewLine substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(startRange, removedNewLine.length-startRange)];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, MMMM d, y hh:mm:ss a"];
    NSDate *addedDate = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
}
```

The Problem is the text file contains more than 6 languages. i.e:

> English: Added on Friday, 25 December 2015 20:12:36
>
> Russian: Добавлено: суббота, 26 декабря 2015 г. в 0:16:45
>
> German: Hinzugefügt am Samstag, 26. Dezember 2015 11:02:51
>
> Japanese: 作成日: 2015年12月26日土曜日 11:32:45
>
> Portuguese: Adicionado: sábado, 26 de dezembro de 2015 11:39:53

As you can see the hard coded way of extracting date string using `NSRange` is not really helpful. I can only think of utilising "switch" statement with cases equal to number of language inside the file.

Is there any convenient way of doing this?

EDIT: 1

When I use NSDateDetector to parse NSDate. Here are the results:

> Japanese: Original String: 作成日: 2015年12月26日土曜日 11:32:45 
>   After Parsing: Values: {46,
>   8}{2015-12-26 18:02:45 +0000} 2015-12-26 18:19:44.538
>   WordsWorth[872:32957] stringDateFromDetector:  11:32:45
>
> Russian: Original String: Добавлено: суббота, 26 декабря 2015 г. в
>   0:16:37   After Parsing: Values: {96, 7}{2015-12-25 18:46:37 +0000} 2015-12-26
>   18:19:44.054 WordsWorth[872:32957] stringDateFromDetector:     0:16:37
>
> German: Original String:Hinzugefügt am Samstag, 26. Dezember 2015 11:02:51 
>   After Parsing:{65,
>   38}{2015-12-26 05:32:51 +0000} 2015-12-26 18:19:44.218
>   WordsWorth[872:32957] stringDateFromDetector:  am Samstag, 26.
>   Dezember 2015 11:02:51

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`NSDataDetector`](http://nshipster.com/nsdatadetector/):

```
let string = "English: Added on Friday, 25 December 2015 20:12:36 ----  作成日: 2015年12月26日土曜日 11:32:45"
let types: NSTextCheckingType = [.Date]
let detector = try? NSDataDetector(types: types.rawValue)

detector?.enumerateMatchesInString(string, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, (string as NSString).length)) { (result, flags, _) in
    print(result!.date!)
}
```

The above code prints and matches

> 2015-12-25 19:12:36 +0000
>   2015-12-26 10:32:45 +0000

which are exactly what you want and need.

*beware of the print statement though - too much force unwrapping*

Below is a screenshot demonstrating the parsing of the different dates:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to this magical api. I implemented it. It can recognise most of the language excluding Russian, Japanese and Chinese. In Russian language it only recognise Time, not Date. My question is since now I can get date from the NSRange returned from NSDataDetector, how will I format date (not English one) using DateFormatter.

Comment: @Napier you cannot parse some languages??? I can parse everyone that I tried so far! And regarding how to reformat those in the particular language - that is an entirely different question I have to say. I do not even know what you would want as output there. But feel free to first incorporate the parsing of the dates and then ask a new question where you try to show the different dates with different formats. You can set the `locale` of the NSDateFormatter though.

Comment: @Napier I added a screenshot where you can see that I successfully parse Russian, Japanese and Chinese.

Comment: I have edited my post. At bottom of the post you can see that for Japanese and Russian language, the range which is being returned does not account for Date rather only time. For German the range **{65, 38}** is clearly encompassing date and time from the Original string.

Comment: @Napier Yes, but what do you need the range for anyway? Your question was `How to extract date` and that is easily done with my code - what you are asking now is something entirely different. Please ask a different question and state very clearly there what you have so far and what you want to get.For now accept(+upvote) my answer here since it solves the original question.

Comment: @Napier I will try to answer the new question as well as soon as I understand what exactly you want, but that is too much discussion and too complex for the comment section.

Comment: Problem is when When I log the date from string. For language i.e Japanese, nothing is displayed in console. For debug I logged NSRange returned for those languages and above is the result. It does not capture the date

Comment: Well, let it go. Appreciate your valuable time you gave.

Comment: @Napier I am unsure what you mean, as you can see on my screenshot everything logs correctly. But that is exactly what I mean - I would need to see your code. **BUT** don't include that in your question since that is an entirely different question. I have no idea what your "range" logic is or what it is supposed to be. You already have a `NSDate` object at hand that you can operate on, no need to do any range magic no more - as said already, feel free to ask a new question if you can clearly state what you need.

Comment: @Napier often rephrasing your problem into a question and thinking how to explain the problem in detail is enough for you yourself to stumble upon the actual solution - therefore go ahead and start asking a new question, it is the better option for everyone :)